# Links directed to <map> <areas>

Tags: html, css, area

I have made a HTML page with an image map over an image.
This image spans over multiple screens and I want to add anchor links to area of the image.

I tried to use something like:

```
<a href="#Area1">LinkToArea1</a></br>
```

and

```
<area id="Area1" shape=rect coords=X1,Y1,X2,Y2  href="http://www.perdu.com" title="Perdu"/>
```

under the map tag,
but while using the same id under the img tag works, this won't do for an area.

What are the html or css solutions to manage this, apart of cutting the images in pieces
(this is indeed the evident solution but it is not possible, I have thousands to do and the cutting would have to fit what has already been done with the maps - that are provided to me by a third party)?

Thanks by advance

Comment: Can you try to build a demo please?

Comment: please post whatever code you've tried along with the question. A fiddle would be helpful. http://jsfiddle.net/